# How to create a dataframe with custom columns?

Tags: r

I need to create a dataframe and passing the name of the columns with variables.

Now, I can do: `df$name1 df$name2`

BUT

How to do the same thing having `'name1'` and `'name2`' in a variable? How can I do some thing like:

`df$THE_VARIABLE` (that have the name of the column)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do this, use the `[[` operator:

```
df[[the_variable]]
```

Here is an example using `iris`:

```
> someCol <- "Species"
> head(iris[[someCol]])
[1] setosa setosa setosa setosa setosa setosa
Levels: setosa versicolor virginica
```